# How to trigger functions inside set in Swift

Tags: swift

I am a C# Developer and I have the following issue. I have a property on my second view controller using the get and set I want to trigger a function.

below is what I want to say.

let's say I have FirstVC and SecondVC

on my SecondVC I have the following

```
var _pStruct: MyTestStruct = MyTestStruct()
var pStruct: MyTestStruct(){ 
get 
  {
    return _pStruct
  }
set
  {
    _pStruct = newValue
    //Here is the Function I want to Trigger.
    MyFunctionToTrigger()
  }
}
```

and On my FirstVc

inside the tableView didSelectRowAt Function

when before or After presenting the SecondVC (I don't know which is more appropriate)

```
SecondVC.pStruct = lopStruct
```

What I expect here to happen is : after I set SecondVC.pStruct to lopStruct 
to go to the Set section of the property in SecondVC and trigger the function
but this does not happen. it never gets in there.. 
any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't it the `didSet` observer what you are looking for?

Comment: The code you've shown us doesn't compile (`var pStruct: MyTestStruct() { get {...} set {...} }` isn't valid Swift, you need to remove the `()` & if you want to access it on a type such as `SecondVC`, it needs to be a `static`/`class` property). Please show us your actual code. Also as a side note it's best to let Swift infer type annotations wherever you can (e.g `var _pStruct = MyTestStruct()`).

Comment: didSet did the magic:) thanks Vadian